# how run junit + maven with options in intellij 10.5.1 (clean install -Dtest=ClassName)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, configure

How can i run mvn with options in intellij 10.5.1 ?
I mean, is it possible or create additional command to run:

```
clean install -Dtest=myClassName //?
```

Can i add this in the tab where i see:

clean

install

validate

and etc. ?

Temporary i use it in console. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure... easiest way is to right click on the lifecycle goal 'install' in the 'Maven projects' panel and select 'Create "Your project name" [install]'. This should bring up the 'Create Run/Debug Configuration' dialog. Simply change the goals to those required (space separated). The properties are on the 'Runner' tab in a table.

Comment: i tried with no result, can you gice any tutorial? I need use sth like this: -s "C:\Program Files\apache-maven-2.0.11\conf" -Dselenium.host=localhost and etc...

Comment: What didn't work? it seems pretty straight forward...create a Run configuration of type Maven and add in the properties that you require.